# Variable Parameter for UIView draw function Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview

My app functions like this:

The time of day is pulled from NSDate and separated into components in an updateTime function in my ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation



class ViewController: UIViewController {



    func updateTime() {

        var date:NSDate = NSDate()
        var calendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        var components:NSDateComponents = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: date)
        var hour = components.hour
        var minute = components.minute
        var seconds = components.second

        var time = "\(hour) : \(minute) : \(seconds)"
        println("\(hour)")




    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)        




    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

On viewDidLoad, the timer begins, calling the function updateTime() which pulls the NSDate and separates it into its hour, minute and second components.

Using the app PaintCode to create Core Graphics draw methods, I then created a Clock Face, which draws 12 separate circles - the initial 12 circles are the EMPTY Drawings. Using the NSDate hour component, my system seeks to determine how many of those empty 12 circles it needs to fill in with core graphics. Using the timer, I wish to update this data each second to keep the core-graphics drawn hour UIView indicator up to date whenever the user has the app open on their screen. I will later do the same with minutes and seconds.

In the design of my app, each hour, minute and second has an additional graphic drawn out. My thinking (I'm probably overthinking this) led me to use enumeration to draw each hour circle out based on the hour reported by NSDate, carrying that "HH" value over to correspond with an individual case ordering the drawing. The same would be done with minute and second tick marks.

This code snippet below is from the UIView file I call ClockFace01 that the UIView in the View Controller is classed to. In the function drawCanvas, I seek to take an integer variable captured from the component.hour of the updateTime() function each second, and somehow update the drawRect method to keep the UIView clock face up to date.

```
    import UIKit



@IBDesignable
class ClockFace01: UIView {

    func updateTime() {

        func drawCanvas(canvas:Int) {
            switch canvas {

            case 00:




                //// EMPTY1 Drawing
                var eMPTY1Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(127, 49.47, 24, 24))
                ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
                eMPTY1Path.lineWidth = 1
                eMPTY1Path.stroke()


                //// EMPTY2 Drawing
                var eMPTY2Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(149.51, 71.98, 24, 24))
                ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
                eMPTY2Path.lineWidth = 1
                eMPTY2Path.stroke()


                //// EMPTY3 Drawing
                var eMPTY3Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(157.75, 102.73, 24, 24))
                ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
                eMPTY3Path.lineWidth = 1
                eMPTY3Path.stroke()


                //// EMPTY4 Drawing
                var eMPTY4Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(149.51, 133.48, 24, 24))
                ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
                eMPTY4Path.lineWidth = 1
                eMPTY4Path.stroke()


                //// EMPTY5 Drawing
                var eMPTY5Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(127, 155.99, 24, 24))
                ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
                eMPTY5Path.lineWidth = 1
                eMPTY5Path.stroke()


                //// EMPTY6 Drawing
                var eMPTY6Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(96.25, 164.23, 24, 24))
                ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
                eMPTY6Path.lineWidth = 1
                eMPTY6Path.stroke()


                //// EMPTY7 Drawing
                var eMPTY7Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(65.5, 155.99, 24, 24))
                ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
                eMPTY7Path.lineWidth = 1
                eMPTY7Path.stroke()


                //// EMPTY8 Drawing
                var eMPTY8Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(42.99, 133.48, 24, 24))
                ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
                eMPTY8Path.lineWidth = 1
                eMPTY8Path.stroke()


                //// EMPTY9 Drawing
                var eMPTY9Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(34.75, 102.73, 24, 24))
                ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
                eMPTY9Path.lineWidth = 1
                eMPTY9Path.stroke()


                //// EMPTY10 Drawing
                var eMPTY10Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(42.99, 71.98, 24, 24))
                ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
                eMPTY10Path.lineWidth = 1
                eMPTY10Path.stroke()


                //// EMPTY11 Drawing
                var eMPTY11Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(65.5, 49.47, 24, 24))
                ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
                eMPTY11Path.lineWidth = 1
                eMPTY11Path.stroke()

                //// EMPTY12 Drawing
                var eMPTY12Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(96.25, 41.23, 24, 24))
                ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
                eMPTY12Path.lineWidth = 1
                eMPTY12Path.stroke()

            case 01, 13:

                //// Color Declarations
                let color0 = UIColor(red: 0.894, green: 0.000, blue: 0.476, alpha: 1.000)

                //// HOUR1 Drawing
                var hOUR1Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(127, 49.47, 24, 24))
                color0.setFill()
                hOUR1Path.fill()

            case 02, 14:

                //// Color Declarations
                let color0 = UIColor(red: 0.894, green: 0.000, blue: 0.476, alpha: 1.000)

                //// HOUR2 Drawing
                var hOUR2Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(149.51, 71.98, 24, 24))
                color0.setFill()
                hOUR2Path.fill()

            case 03, 15:

                //// Color Declarations
                let color0 = UIColor(red: 0.894, green: 0.000, blue: 0.476, alpha: 1.000)

                //// HOUR3 Drawing
                var hOUR3Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(157.75, 102.73, 24, 24))
                color0.setFill()
                hOUR3Path.fill()

            case 04, 16:

                //// Color Declarations
                let color0 = UIColor(red: 0.894, green: 0.000, blue: 0.476, alpha: 1.000)

                //// HOUR4 Drawing
                var hOUR4Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(149.51, 133.48, 24, 24))
                color0.setFill()
                hOUR4Path.fill()

            case 05, 17:

                //// Color Declarations
                let color0 = UIColor(red: 0.894, green: 0.000, blue: 0.476, alpha: 1.000)

                //// HOUR5 Drawing
                var hOUR5Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(127, 155.99, 24, 24))
                color0.setFill()
                hOUR5Path.fill()

            case 06, 18:

                //// Color Declarations
                let color0 = UIColor(red: 0.894, green: 0.000, blue: 0.476, alpha: 1.000)

                //// HOUR6 Drawing
                var hOUR6Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(96.25, 164.23, 24, 24))
                color0.setFill()
                hOUR6Path.fill()

            case 07, 19:

                //// Color Declarations
                let color0 = UIColor(red: 0.894, green: 0.000, blue: 0.476, alpha: 1.000)

                //// HOUR7 Drawing
                var hOUR7Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(65.5, 155.99, 24, 24))
                color0.setFill()
                hOUR7Path.fill()

            case 08, 20:

                //// Color Declarations
                let color0 = UIColor(red: 0.894, green: 0.000, blue: 0.476, alpha: 1.000)

                //// HOUR8 Drawing
                var hOUR8Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(42.99, 133.48, 24, 24))
                color0.setFill()
                hOUR8Path.fill()

            case 09, 21:

                //// Color Declarations
                let color0 = UIColor(red: 0.894, green: 0.000, blue: 0.476, alpha: 1.000)

                //// HOUR9 Drawing
                var hOUR9Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(34.75, 102.73, 24, 24))
                color0.setFill()
                hOUR9Path.fill()

            case 10, 22:

                //// Color Declarations
                let color0 = UIColor(red: 0.894, green: 0.000, blue: 0.476, alpha: 1.000)

                //// HOUR10 Drawing
                var hOUR10Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(42.99, 71.98, 24, 24))
                color0.setFill()
                hOUR10Path.fill()

            case 11, 23:

                //// Color Declarations
                let color0 = UIColor(red: 0.894, green: 0.000, blue: 0.476, alpha: 1.000)

                //// HOUR11 Drawing
                var hOUR11Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(65.5, 49.47, 24, 24))
                color0.setFill()
                hOUR11Path.fill()

            case 12, 24:

                //// Color Declarations
                let color0 = UIColor(red: 0.894, green: 0.000, blue: 0.476, alpha: 1.000)

                //// HOUR12 Drawing
                var hOUR12Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(96.25, 41.23, 24, 24))
                color0.setFill()
                hOUR12Path.fill()

            default:
                //// EMPTY12 Drawing
                var eMPTY12Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(96.25, 41.23, 24, 24))
                ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
                eMPTY12Path.lineWidth = 1
                eMPTY12Path.stroke()


            }
        }

        var date:NSDate = NSDate()
        var calendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        var components:NSDateComponents = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: date)
        var hour = components.hour
        var minute = components.minute
        var seconds = components.second

        var time = "\(hour) : \(minute) : \(seconds)"
        println("\(hour)")



    }


    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)



        //// EMPTY12 Drawing
        var eMPTY12Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(96.25, 41.23, 24, 24))
        ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
        eMPTY12Path.lineWidth = 1
        eMPTY12Path.stroke()


        //// EMPTY1 Drawing
        var eMPTY1Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(127, 49.47, 24, 24))
        ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
        eMPTY1Path.lineWidth = 1
        eMPTY1Path.stroke()


        //// EMPTY2 Drawing
        var eMPTY2Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(149.51, 71.98, 24, 24))
        ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
        eMPTY2Path.lineWidth = 1
        eMPTY2Path.stroke()


        //// EMPTY3 Drawing
        var eMPTY3Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(157.75, 102.73, 24, 24))
        ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
        eMPTY3Path.lineWidth = 1
        eMPTY3Path.stroke()


        //// EMPTY4 Drawing
        var eMPTY4Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(149.51, 133.48, 24, 24))
        ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
        eMPTY4Path.lineWidth = 1
        eMPTY4Path.stroke()


        //// EMPTY5 Drawing
        var eMPTY5Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(127, 155.99, 24, 24))
        ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
        eMPTY5Path.lineWidth = 1
        eMPTY5Path.stroke()


        //// EMPTY6 Drawing
        var eMPTY6Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(96.25, 164.23, 24, 24))
        ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
        eMPTY6Path.lineWidth = 1
        eMPTY6Path.stroke()


        //// EMPTY7 Drawing
        var eMPTY7Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(65.5, 155.99, 24, 24))
        ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
        eMPTY7Path.lineWidth = 1
        eMPTY7Path.stroke()


        //// EMPTY8 Drawing
        var eMPTY8Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(42.99, 133.48, 24, 24))
        ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
        eMPTY8Path.lineWidth = 1
        eMPTY8Path.stroke()


        //// EMPTY9 Drawing
        var eMPTY9Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(34.75, 102.73, 24, 24))
        ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
        eMPTY9Path.lineWidth = 1
        eMPTY9Path.stroke()


        //// EMPTY10 Drawing
        var eMPTY10Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(42.99, 71.98, 24, 24))
        ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
        eMPTY10Path.lineWidth = 1
        eMPTY10Path.stroke()


        //// EMPTY11 Drawing
        var eMPTY11Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(65.5, 49.47, 24, 24))
        ClockStyleKit.color1.setStroke()
        eMPTY11Path.lineWidth = 1
        eMPTY11Path.stroke()
    }
```

In the above

Comment: What do you mean your program "does not like that"? Are you getting a compiler error? A crash? Or it's just not drawing as you'd expect?

Comment: Seconding @Cadin's comment: You really need to provide more information. Exactly what is or isn't happening that isn't/is supposed to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `UIView` is told to draw **by the system** when the system calls `drawRect()`. Are you calling your `drawCanvas()` method from `drawRect()` or are you calling it directly from elsewhere (like your `updateTime()` method)?

If you're not drawing as a result of a (system) call to `drawRect()` that's your problem. Either do your drawing inside `drawRect()` or by methods called from your `drawRect()` implementation. You tell the system your view is "dirty" by sending `setNeedsDisplay()` to your view when it needs to be redrawn and let the *system*  call your view's `drawRect()` at its convenience.

**Hint:** The system knows way better than you do when it's actually best to redraw a view or a portion of a view, especially since it may need to blend transparent/translucent parts with views "behind" or "in front of" it. The system knows what regions (all or a sub-rectangle) of all the views that flagged themselves for redrawing and optimizes redrawing them so that it can blend properly without asking all views (dirty or not) to redraw themselves. It's not your job (nor is it your business) to track all of this; it's only your job to make your custom view as efficient at drawing *itself* as possible. To that end, you might only want to flag a certain rectangle as needing display (via `setNeedsDisplayInRect()`) if the whole thing doesn't need to be redrawn, etc. But definitely avoid fighting the system. Use the appropriate drawing hook and flagging.

In your case, you probably want to call `setNeedsDisplay()` at then end of your `updateTime()` method.

**Update based on comments**

I think I see your problem.

1. Don't trigger more drawing (by creating a timer) from your `drawRect()` method.
2. Your `updateTime()` method should do only that: update the time. Break down the current date and update your view's internal state when the timer fires (your method is called), then flag for display via `setNeedsDisplay()`. That's it.
3. Get rid of your `drawCanvas()` method entirely; it's only confusing things. Move its contents into `drawRect()` and leave it there unless you have good reason to compartmentalize it into subroutines. It's short enough that for now, you don't.
4. Set up your timer *once*.
5. All of this goes in your view class.

Comment: That's essentially where I'm stuck. When I place draw methods in my override drawRect() method, it works - I get images in my UIView. I want to draw more images in my UIView based on the time variables I have collected from my updateTime() method. I want this to update every 1 second, using my NSTimer. Every hour, minute and second will represent a different set of drawn images to visually represent the time.

Comment: So it's back to the comments in your question: We need more information. What's happening that shouldn't, or what's not happening that should? Are you saying the timer never fires?

Comment: You really need to provide as much detail as possible or you risk having your question voted closed.

Comment: My main point of confusion is where to place the "var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)" line in relation to the updateTime() method. Do the timer and the updateTime() methods belong in my UIView class attached to my UIView? Right now I am getting a lot of invalid context errors whenever I try to use drawCanvas(hour) to pass along that hour integer. Does my drawCanvas(canvas:Int) function need to be nested in my updateTime() function, in the top level of the class, or somewhere else?

Comment: Example of the errors: May  7 18:33:18 Alexs-Mac-Pro.home NookaTime[8315] <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Comment: Post. Your. Code. Without it, we're forced to either write a class for you or keep trying to pull information out of you a little bit at a time like a dentist pulling teeth. If you post your code, we can quickly and efficiently tell you what's wrong and/or fix it in place.

Comment: I updated the original post with the code. I apologize for being mentally slow and difficult to assist. Your help is graciously appreciated.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Should I still use the switch/case when placing all of the draw methods in drawRect?  2) By view class I assume you are referring to the UIView class rather than the view controller? Very helpful, thank you.

Comment: 1) I don't know. You never posted the relevant code that details what calls this method and determines what "canvas" int to send. 2) Yes. I'd have said "view controller" or "controller" otherwise. If you post your latest code (append it to your question; leave the original intact so it can help others learn what you're learning), we can continue to shape it.